# zsh function doesn't work due to quotation mar

Tags: shell, gitlab, zsh

today I edited this function, found around in internet, on my .zshrc.
The point is that, if a enter every single line in shell it works and creates the repo in gitlab.
Evoking it as function it returns:

gitdir:5: no matches found: https://gitlab.mine.my/api/v4/projects?private_token=HI-U-ALL

The function is this:

```
   function gitdir() {
      repo=$1           
      token=HI-U-ALL            
      GITLAB=gitlab.mine.my            
      test -z $repo && echo "Repo name required." 1>&2 && exit 1            
      curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://$GITLAB/api/v4/projects?private_token=$token \
      -d "{ \name\: \$repo\ }"    }
```

The issue is with the "" of the curl call, but I can't solve to problem, there are many workaround
but  definitely not elegant as a native function.
Can anyone suggest a possible solution?
Thanks in advance.
Rob

I already tried to change the quotation marks but curl is really stuck to them.
I'd like to simply automate the procedure

Comment: I don't believe that _if_ you _enter_ the _single line_ _`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://$GITLAB/api/v4/projects?private_token=$token \
      -d "{ \name\: \$repo\ }"`_ _in_ _zsh_ _it works_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question mark is a glob character for the shell, and zsh tries to do filename generation in your https parameter. The simplest solution is to wrap the argument between double-quotes. Alternatively, you can escape the question mark:

```
... "https://$GITLAB/api/v4/projects?private_token=$token" ...
```

or

```
... https://$GITLAB/api/v4/projects\?private_token=$token ...
```